# how to proportionally scale a div with images inside?

Tags: javascript, css, html, image

I need help on this..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsQsD.jpg

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrLQWO

there are 3 images inside `<div>` (eg.diagram A)

I am trying to scale my `<div>` via JavaScript (eg.diagram C)

but the images inside do not scale with my `<div>` (eg.diagram B)

ANYONE?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FsQsD.jpg

Comment: Just set one of the width and height attribute.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the size of your images with percentage.

Comment: is it not possible to adjust the size of the div, then it's content (images) follows?